# Get properties of properties of a class

Tags: c#, reflection, system.reflection

I want to get the properties of the properties of a class.

What I have right now:

```
foreach (var v in test.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    foreach (var p in v.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
    }
}
```

The first `foreach` loop works fine and gets the properties of the class variable `test`. However, in the second loop, I get output such as `MemberType`, `ReflectedType`, `Module` etc.. not actual properties.

My goal is to get the properties of the properties of a class and then edit their value (truncate them using another function).

Thanks.

Comment: v is a `PropertyInfo` object, not the property's value type. You want `var p in v.PropertyType.GetProperties()`

Comment: They are properties from another classes @GrantWinney. Got my problem fixed though, thanks everyone!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On the second loop `GetType()` returns a `PropertyInfo` object. You have to get the propertyType of v as `v.PropertyType.GetProperties()` to achieve what you want.

So, the code should be:

```
foreach (var v in test.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    foreach (var p in v.PropertyType.GetProperties())
    {
        // Stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The type returned by `v.GetType()` is that of PropertyInfo, because `v` is a property info.  You don't want the properties **of the PropertyInfo type**, you want the properties of the type itself.

Use `v.PropertyType`, not `v.GetType()`.

Answer (score 0):

GetProperties() gets you PropertyInfo objects which tell you information about the properties of the object. You need to use `GetValue` to actually get the values of those properties. From there you can repeat the process to get the values of that object's properties.

```
foreach (var v in test.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    var propertyValue = v.GetValue(test);
    foreach (var p in propertyValue.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        var subPropertyValue = p.GetValue(propertyValue);
        Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", p.Name, subPropertyValue);
    }
}
```

After editing the value use `SetValue` to persist it back to the object.